# How to register my go lang microservice in Spring Eureka Service Discovery

Tags: java, spring-boot, go, microservices, netflix-eureka

I want to register my external go lang micro-service in eureka service discovery, but I dunno where I am doing a mistake.

This is what I tried from my end:

**Go lang config file**

```
package configuration

import (
    "net"
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/LdCPT.png)
    "github.com/ArthurHlt/go-eureka-client/eureka"
)

func EurekClientConfig() {
    // Get the IP address of the local machine
    addrs, err := net.InterfaceAddrs()
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    var ipAddress string
    for _, addr := range addrs {
        if ipnet, ok := addr.(*net.IPNet); ok && !ipnet.IP.IsLoopback() && ipnet.IP.To4() != nil {
            ipAddress = ipnet.IP.String()
            break
        }
    }

    // Initialize the Eureka client with server URL
    client := eureka.NewClient([]string{"http://localhost:8761/eureka/"})
    // Create the instance information for the GoLang service

    // eureka.NewInstanceInfo(appName, ipAddr, hostname, port, securePort, ttl, secure)
    instance := eureka.NewInstanceInfo(
        "localhost",
        "RESTAURANT-SERVICE",
        ipAddress,
        8085,
        30,
        false,
    )

    // Register the instance with the Eureka server
    client.RegisterInstance("RESTAURANT-SERVICE", instance)
    client.SendHeartbeat(instance.App, instance.HostName)
}
```

Go compiles this file perfectly without any error but in eureka server, this failed to registered.

[image]

Eureka server application.properties file

```
server.port=8761

spring.application.name=eureka-server

eureka.client.register-with-eureka=false
eureka.client.fetch-registry=false

eureka.server.wait-time-in-ms-when-sync-empty=0
eureka.server.enable-self-preservation=false

eureka.instance.prefer-ip-address=true
eureka.instance.lease-renewal-interval-in-seconds=30
eureka.instance.lease-expiration-duration-in-seconds=90


spring.cloud.config.import-check.enabled=false
```

I just want to register my go microservice on eureka server.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this and did some debugging and found the error on this line...

```
client := eureka.NewClient([]string{"http://localhost:8761/eureka/"})
```

When you use the above statement and try to print the client's details, it will print something like this...

```
Printing Client Details..
&{{  [] 1s } 0xc000022a50 0xc000022a80 <nil> <nil> <nil>}
```

and Instance Details will be, which means it fails to register the instance...

```
Printing Instance Details...
<nil> instance not found
```

However, if you replace your NewClient line with this.. it will register your instance

```
client := eureka.NewClient([]string{"http://localhost:8761/eureka"})
```

It will register your instance, and you can get details like this. To print instance details I used this line...

```
fmt.Println(client.GetInstance(instance.App, instance.HostName))
```

The output of this...

```
&{localhost  http://localhost:8085/info  RESTAURANT-SERVICE 127.0.0.1 http://localhost:8085  UP 0xc000182280 0xc0001822d0 0xc000186480 0xc000184200 0xc0001a83c0 false 1700182376754 1700182376753 ADDED UNKNOWN 1 } <nil>
```

What's the difference?
The additional slash "/" symbol made the difference, maybe the repo owner has failed to handle this.

For more details, you can see [Line 15](https://github.com/ArthurHlt/go-eureka-client/blob/3b8dfe04ec6ca280d50f96356f765edb845a00e4/README.md?plain=1#L15) of Readme document of git repo.

I'm also providing the code that I used.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"

    "github.com/ArthurHlt/go-eureka-client/eureka"
)

func EurekaClientConfig() {

    // Initialize the Eureka client with server URL
    client := eureka.NewClient([]string{"http://localhost:8761/eureka"})
    fmt.Println("Printing Client Details..")
    fmt.Println(client)
    // eureka.NewInstanceInfo(hostname, appName, ipAddr, port, securePort, ttl, secure)
    instance := eureka.NewInstanceInfo(
        "localhost",
        "RESTAURANT-SERVICE",
        "127.0.0.1",
        8085,
        30,
        false,
    )

    // Register the instance with the Eureka server
    client.RegisterInstance("RESTAURANT-SERVICE", instance)
    client.SendHeartbeat(instance.App, instance.HostName)
    fmt.Println("Printing Instance Details...")
    fmt.Println(client.GetInstance(instance.App, instance.HostName))
}

func main() {
    EurekaClientConfig()
}
```